# API response returned in JavaScript returning undefined unless I do &&

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I am using react and there seems to be an issue with the load time of the API. Like lets say I am trying to get:

```
<div>{movieInfo.full_name}</div>
```

which is one of the fields being returned. If I were to do the above, it would throw an error.

However, if I did the following it would work:

```
{ movieInfo && <div>{movieInfo.full_name}</div>}
```

This can be pretty inefficient and messy if I had to do this for all other fields being returned from that endpoint. Think has something to do with race condition. Is there any way I can combat this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code to this:

```
  <div>{movieInfo?.full_name}</div>
```

If this doesn't work, you can do something like this:

```
 if (!movieInfo) return <LoadingIndicator />

 return (
    <div>{movieInfo.full_name}</div>
 );
```

You can return null or a loading idicator like a spinner if movieInfo is not yet loaded.

Comment: That is giving me a syntax error. May have something to do with my node version

Comment: You can check this condition only once for all fields. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this for example:

```
{
  movieInfo ? 
(
  <>
    <div>{movieInfo.full_name}</div>
    <div>{movieInfo.year}</div>
  </>
) : Loader
}
```

or if still it looks messy
you can create variable and check if movieInfo exist then you display data
like this:

```
let movies = <Loader />
if(movieInfo) {
   movies = (
     <>
       <div>{movieInfo.full_name}</div>
       <div>{movieInfo.year}</div>
    </>
 )
}
return movies
```